# For loop not running in if case

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I have a problem where my for loop doesn't seem to run in my if statement, the for loop is supposed to print all the values in my list.

```
import java.util.*;

public class kapitel12 {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Float> temperatur = new ArrayList<Float>();

    while(true)
    {           
        System.out.println("[L]ägg till temperaturmätning");
        System.out.println("[S]kriv ut alla temperaturer och medeltemperatur");
        System.out.println("[T]ag bort temperaturmätning");
        System.out.println("[A]vsluta");

        String val = scan.next();

        if (val.equals("L") || val.equals("l"))
        {
            System.out.println("Lägg till temperatur");

            float temp = Float.parseFloat(scan.next());
            temperatur.add(temp);
            System.out.println(temperatur);
        }
        else if (val.equals("S") || val.equals("s")) 
        {
            System.out.println("Alla mätningar");


            for(int i = 0; i < temperatur.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Mätning" + i + ":" + temperatur.get(i));

            }
    }       
}   
}
```

Comment: try changing to `String val = scan.nextLine();`

Comment: does the code other than the loop part works? cause I agree with @ScaryWombat

Comment: Only on the Enter key, the input is passed to java. Pressing just L/S will not register

Answer (score 1):

The loop runs but the size of *temperatur* is 0, this means the loops end immedently. The *temperatur* is filled in the **if** clause, but if you go to **if** then the next clause **else if** will not be executed.

You have to fill *temperatur* before reading the list or define *temperatur* as class var not as local var.

Answer (score 0):

logical conditions in nested `if` statement are mutually exclusive, only one of them will be satisfied at time if the condition is met.

Because `val` can have one value at time
for example if `val="S"` the code block in the first `if` will not be executed that results in your `v=temperatur` to be empty because it is the first block that adds elements to it.